# HTML page not compatible with IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have an HTML page which works fine in all browsers but obviously it has an issue with IE. When I open it with IE everything is all over the place.

I have tried different script and no luck at all.

This is what I have so far:

HTML

```
<div class="myrow">
  <div class="column1">
                        <div class="services-post services-single-post">
                            <div class="single-post-title">
                                <h2>Web development</h2>
                            </div>

                            <div class="single-post-image">
                                <img src="img/web.jpg" alt="Post Title">
                            </div>

                            <div class="single-post-info">
                            </div>

                            <div class="single-post-content">
                                <p>Add description here...</p>
                            <a href="webDevelopment.html" class="btn">Read more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column2">
                        <div class="services-post services-single-post">
                            <div class="single-post-title">
                                <h2>Mobile Development</h2>
                            </div>

                            <div class="single-post-image">
                                <img src="img/s1.png" alt="Post Title">
                            </div>

                            <div class="single-post-info">
                            </div>

                            <div class="single-post-content">
                                <p>Add description here...</p>
                            <a href="services-post.html" class="btn">Read more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.myrow{
  display:table;
  margin: 0 -10px 0;
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
} 

.column1, .column2{
  width:50%;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #e8e8e8;

}
```

Please assist. Thank you

Comment: Which versions of IE/Edge?

Comment: What do you mean everything is all over the place? I just loaded that into a jsfiddle and everything looks fine...
https://jsfiddle.net/hrv3c8h0/

Comment: my images are not nicely posioned . they are not in rows and columns

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. I don't see the issue, [**there's two elements side-by-side**](https://jsfiddle.net/hrv3c8h0/2/) which seems to be what you're going for. Also, it woks in IE 11 and 10 for me. Are we missing some CSS?

Comment: in IE my images do not get resized accordingly which makes my columns and rows too large. This also makes my columns uneven

Comment: What's too large? There's nothing in your CSS that limits their size. Your columns are going to be uneven if your images have different heights. It would be great if you made a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using an image placeholder service like [**placehold.it**](http://placehold.it) using the same dimensions as your original images.